# Images of sun/stars/spaceship show rays

Tags: optics

Looking at the images (still or moving) of a bright source of light (similar to the sun or a launching spaceship) I often observe an even (?) number of rays, which seem to be related to the properties of the lens system being used during the image capture. See [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=KPstuy_pqDo&t=88s) or [here](https://www.google.co.jp/amp/s/gizmodo.com/5926497/what-happens-when-you-stare-at-the-sun/amp?source=images).

What is the explanation of this phenomenon?

Comment: Absolutely! My fault, sorry!

Comment: no apologies needed :)